# Add a period at nth position from the last for multiple files in a folder

Tags: regex, perl, rename

While doing bulk renaming mistakenly I removed periods from extensions of many of my files and also it duplicated the extensions in every file

Now I would like to add them back

My Files look like this now

```
A Nightmare On Elm Street 720p Bluray X264-Pahe In mkv mkv
Austin Powers International Man Of Mystery 480p Bluray 300mb-Pahe In mkv mkv
Death_warrant_1990_720p_bluray_x264_750mb-Pahe In mkv mkv
Die Frau Des Polizisten 720p Bluray X264-Pahe In mkv mkv
```

So What I would like to do is remove the extra extension part, as well as add a period just before the extension so that it will look like a video file

That is..once I rename it should look like below

```
A Nightmare On Elm Street 720p Bluray X264-Pahe In.mkv
Austin Powers International Man Of Mystery 480p Bluray 300mb-Pahe In.mkv
Death_warrant_1990_720p_bluray_x264_750mb-Pahe In.mkv
Die Frau Des Polizisten 720p Bluray X264-Pahe In.mkv
```

Is there any regex that I could use? or can I use perl rename technique with regex to do so?

Comment: You should use linux command [rename](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) for this purpose.

Comment: `rename s/mkv mkv/\.mkv/ *mkv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
s/^(.*) (\w\w\w) (\2)$/\1.\3/
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/4hnndV/1/)

Or, this works too:

```
s/ (\w\w\w) (\1)$/.\1/
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/4hnndV/2/)

Comment: That worked well
Thank you